# Support for multiple byte ranges on Azure blob read/write

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We need random read (and later write) access to thousands of discrete ranges (each in the order of a few KBs) within very large binary blobs (in the order of 100s of GB). The current APIs force us to submit a single request for each such range. One negative aspect is billing, of course, but the main problem is the client-side and network loads for handling all these requests!

Are there any known ways of avoiding the massive overhead for access patterns like this?

Assume that reformatting the data is not viable, since the access patterns vary.  Replicating the data in a multitude of versions optimized for each access pattern variation is also highly undesirable, for several reasons (optimization lead time, storage costs, data management, plus not all access patterns can be predicted - the known ones might not even be used).

Extending the "Range" REST API header to [support multiple ranges](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/38567287-support-for-multiple-byte-ranges-on-blob-read-writ) would be ideal solution, but obviously that's not ours to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no other nice ways to do that. The current api(I think you're using [get blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) api) only supports a single range not multi-ranges and detail is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-blob-service-operations).

As of now, there is no good workaround for this issue. I see the user voice you submitted, it's a good feedback and already upvoted for it. Hope the MS team can implement it in the future release.